# vtk uses more and more memory and becomes slow.

Tags: c++, vtk

I encountered a memory leak in my application and pinned it down that it is
something related to vtk. I'm using vtk 6.1.0 on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2012 all in 64bit.

I encountered this behaviour with more algorithms of vtk.
It is definetly not the OS who is meesing with the memory, but vtk. It seems that on every call of update vtk creates objects and puts them into a sort of update queue and does not remove in the end. Consider this code:

```
#include <vtkImageConstantPad.h>
#include <vtkImageData.h>
#include <ctime>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c=0;
    clock_t start;
    size_t iterations = 1000;
    while (c != '.'){
         c = getchar();
         start = clock();
         for(size_t i=0; i<iterations; ++i){
             vtkImageConstantPad* pad = vtkImageConstantPad::New();
             vtkImageData* test = vtkImageData::New();
             test->SetExtent(0,1,0,1,0,1);
             test->AllocateScalars(VTK_FLOAT,1);
             pad->SetInputData(test);
             pad->SetOutputWholeExtent(0,2,0,2,0,2);
             pad->Update(); //this is what makes it bad
             pad->Delete();
             test->Delete();
         }
         std::cout << "Time for " << iterations << ": " << static_cast<double>(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "sec" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output for me is:

```
Time for 1000: 0.816sec
Time for 1000: 1.879sec
Time for 1000: 3.454sec
etc.
```

So it consumes more memory and more time every call to `update()` , although all objects in the for-loop scope get destroyed. Can anyone confirm this on other platforms or knows how to fix that?

Comment: It's not a memory leak, it's an operating system "optimization" that keeps previously allocated memory mapped to the process. If the system will be getting low on free memory the memory will be remapped to another process as needed. It's nothing to worry about.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This should have been an answer.

Comment: @nwp I (and many others) have posted such answers many times before. I'm just to lazy to find one right now to mark as duplicate. :)

Comment: If it is a OS optimization, then why doesn't it occur without the update? Here the memory allocated by new is freed and reused at the end of the loop, why doesn't the os do the same for objects created in the update() function?

Comment: If its no mem leak, then why does the memory usage increases after the first loop iteration? the application has free memory mapped to it to allocate all memory for the second iteration within this memory. There is no need for windows to allocate new memory for the app! So the behaviour shows that there eihter is a memory leak or the optimization does not do what it was invented for: Avoiding (de)allocations of new memory for an application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further investigation I found out that this problem does not occur on all machines.
In the end I found that my Bitdefender Antivirus is somehow messing with the program and leads to this wierd behaviour. When I turn it off, everything works as expected.

Comment: Hey, same for me, i also have bit defender and can reproduce the problem as well as the solution.